# Scrolling broken on SF1 for ios/android?

Tags: salesforce1-app, ios, salesforce1-platform, android

I have a component which will perform an initial render, then will grow larger once some new information is fetched. Even though the size of the elements on the screen has gotten bigger, I'm unable to scroll further down on my screen.

This only happens on Salesforce1 for ios/android (not for referencing a Lightning component directly by its url on a desktop web browser).

The desired behavior had been working previously - it's hard for me to tell if this is due to a change to the SF1 app, the Winter 16 release, or both.

Lastly, as an extremely strange workaround, I'm able to get scrolling to work by pulling down to see the "Pull to Refresh" message, *not* lifting my finger up, and flicking back down.

Comment: Hi, have you come across a solution for this issue? I am experiencing the same thing